# Arrastar View para abrir nova Activity

Tags: android

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acho que não precisa de código porque é em layout extremamente simples, apenas para dar exemplo.

A minha dúvida é como fazer para ao segurar e puxar essa `Toolbar` para cima, a `Activity` correspondente "suba" junto.

Se não der para fazer isso, pelo menos que isso seja uma `View` aleatória e ela faça a função da `Toolbar`como foi descrito acima.

Comment: também tenho interesse em aprender isso

Comment: Procure por Bottom Sheet.

Comment: exatamente isso que eu queria. Esse foi o melhor tutorial que achei https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031. No site do material design há uma explicação bem completa, mas não tem exemplo de código e não é um tutorial como esse aí